# How do I force a persist to memory of Spark DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm building up many new columns with `withColumn` and window operations (with Python/Spark). This results in a large lineage which slows down the operation. Actually, persisting the DataFrame to disk every couple of steps helps a lot.

But how can I conveniently cache a DataFrame *in memory* and force *materialization* so that lineage is reduced?

(I've seen suggestions about `count`, but I had the impression that only works for RDDs?)

Comment: `count` works for both `RDD` and `DF` (search for `count` here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, count would work for dataframe too. Any action which covers the entire dataframe will suffice (count goes over all records and therefore would materialize the entire dataframe).

Second, it is important to note that the lineage would NOT be reduced by caching. The entire lineage would be analyzed and optimized as part of the code generation. The only difference is that many steps would probably be skipped as the data already materialized from the cache would be used (BTW, this is not always true, there are cases where the optimizer might decide to recalculate based on its internal heuristics).

There are two ways to cut the lineage on a dataframe.

1. Write to disk and reload (which cuts the lineage to the "reading" portion).
2. Use checkpointing (which behind the scenes also saves and loads).

   Checkpointing has the advantage that you can write to a local disk instead of a distributed one (which should take less time), however, this is done through RDDs (even the new interface for checkpointing dataframe directly actually uses the RDD checkpoint behind the scenes) and therefore is larger than the dataframe size which could result in it being slower in practice.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `count` doesn't optimize and skip some calculation? Since a trailing `withColumn` wouldn't change the result of `count`? At what point would `cache` materialize? Because `cache` by itself doesn't do anything yet, so there is not data cached until the very end when the full lineage is already there?!

Comment: I am not 100% sure when you do one cache after another, but in general it should work. So far it always worked for me... You can simply try it and check what happens...